# How to force a meta-data value to type string?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I specified a meta-data in my manifest.xml like this:

```
<meta-data android:value="5555555555" android:name="foo"></meta-data>
```

When accessing the metadata like this:

```
ActivityInfo ai = act.getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(componentName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
Object value = (Object)ai.metaData.get(key);
```

this value gets interpreted as int and - more importantly - incorrectly interpreted (1260588259).

Since the type is determined automatically by the build system ( booleans, ints, floats, and strings ) I wondered if there is any way to force the data type to string.

I tried adding a space at the end ( "5555555555 "), but then the value gets interpreted as 5.5555553E9 float! ).

I also tried using `getString` instead of `get`, but then null is returned.

Any ideas? TIA.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Putting an escaped space in front of the number seems to work:

```
<meta-data android:name="foo" android:value="\ 1234567890"/>
```

The escaped space doesn't appear in the value returned by `get()`.

I have no idea quite how this works, if I'm honest.

If you want [something documented](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html) and therefore more reliable you can always put your string value as a resource and refer to it:

```
<meta-data android:name="foo" android:resource="@string/mynumber"/>
```

Answer (score 9):

I have also such a problem.
My solution is as follows:

```
<meta-data android:value="5555555555\0" android:name="foo"></meta-data>
```

I added at the end of a variable - escape sequence "\0" (NULL - is often used to define the end of a character string (for example, in the language C).

This work for me.

Best regards.

Comment: I used this for a couple years but recently `"5555555555\0"` gets converted to `"55555555550"` As if the backslash was escaping the 0. So this might not be as reliable as using strings.xml file to store the number.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a space, try using a piece of punctuation that should have no role in a numeric value, like a colon, and see if that helps.

Comment: problem is that i really need to have the number unaltered. if possible. i could always use something like "num:5555555555" but i would only do it that way if there really is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this problem and it is a very frustrating that something like a Facebook application id is interpreted as an integer leading to problems due to overflow (of course). I would have thought/hoped it would be possible to override the implicit typing. For example, instead of:

```
<meta-data android:name="value" android:value="12345678901234567890" />
```

it would be nice if we could write:

```
<meta-data android:name="value" android:type="string" android:value="12345678901234567890" />
```

In order to compensate for this, I wrote some supporting code that *requires* manifest attributes to look as follows:

```
<meta-data android:name="value1" android:value="string/12345678901234567890" />
<meta-data android:name="value2" android:value="integer/12345" />
<meta-data android:name="value3" android:value="boolean/true" />
<meta-data android:name="value4" android:value="float/1.34" />
<meta-data android:name="value5" android:value="float/6" />
```

Note that this is intended to look similar to the Android `@string`/`@integer` syntax except that I have dropped the `@`, interpreting this as dropping the level of indirection.

As well as solving the original problem of [0-9]+ always interpreted as integers it seems, it also allows for floats to be specified directly despite looking like an integer.

A further advantage of this is that it is possible to extend the set of types arbitrarily. e.g.

```
<meta-data android:name="myfrac" android:value="fraction/3/7" />
```