# manifestPlaceholders value is not string

Tags: android, android-manifest, build.gradle, android-flavors

In my AndroidManifest.xml file I have the following meta-data tag which should be populated dynamically:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="${FACEBOOK_APP_ID}"/>
```

My gradle file looks like this:

```
manifestPlaceholders = [
                GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID: "A888844613784",
                FACEBOOK_APP_ID: "888570042741264"
        ]
```

After "Build & Assemble" the FACEBOOK_APP_ID in the manifest file looks like this:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="1481023616.000000" />
```

Unfortunately this is not a String, but a float value. That's not correct or what I want.

I know there is another way to define the `FACEBOOK_APP_ID` in the `string.xml` file. But since I have lots of flavors it would be nice and easy to maintain if we put all flavors-related parameters in the `build.gradle` file instead of the `strings.xml` files.

Does anyone know how to avoid the string to float conversion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following code to add a String value to your string resources from a build.gradle file:

```
resValue 'string', 'FACEBOOK_APP_ID', 'facebook_application_id'
```

But I'm not sure if the AndroidManifest.xml file does not support flavor specific strings (I can remember you will get a warning if you try, but I'm not sure).

<strike>You could also try to add a null-terminator to your FACEBOOK_APP_ID manifestPlaceholder as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37719945/1052697) answer:</strike>

```
FACEBOOK_APP_ID: "888570042741264\0"
```

**Edit:**

The code null-terminator method seems not to be working when used directly from the build.gradle file, it does however work when using the null-terminator inside the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="${FACEBOOK_APP_ID}\0"/>
```

Comment: thank you. resValue works and no warning. but FACEBOOK_APP_ID: "888570042741264\0" not working.

Comment: Thanks Rolf, now android:value="${FACEBOOK_APP_ID}\0" works also. you are awesome!

Comment: "${FACEBOOK_APP_ID}\0" does not seem to work (anymore?)

Comment: `"${FACEBOOK_APP_ID}"` didn't work for me. `"@string/FACEBOOK_APP_ID"` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I use manifestPlaceholders and force gradle to recognize the string by escaping the quotes like so:
`manifestPlaceholders = [facebook_app_id:"\"9999000099990000\"",
                         fb_login_protocol_scheme:"fb9999000099990000"]`

You don't need to it for the second param since it has the string `fb` in front.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me (if you do not use flavors, just put resValue into defaultConfig):

```
productFlavors {
    production {
        resValue 'string', 'facebookAppId', '22222222222'
        resValue 'string', 'facebookSchemeId', 'fb22222222222'
    }

    development {
        resValue 'string', 'facebookAppId', '11111111111'
        resValue 'string', 'facebookSchemeId', 'fb11111111111'
    }
}
```

Then in manifest:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebookAppId" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="@string/facebookSchemeId" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just face a similar issue where my facebook values were treated as a number and garbled.

If I make sure to wrap them in " then it works as expected and they are treated as strings.

```
manifestPlaceholders += [FACEBOOK_APP_ID: "\"" + rootProject.facebookAppId + "\"", FACEBOOK_CLIENT_TOKEN: "\"" + rootProject.facebookClientToken + "\""]
```